# When talking about the hardened heart in Islam is it literal or figurative?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Is the hardened heart literal or figurative? Would you feel anything with a hardened heart like as if you're about to cough because you're heart feels some physical thing? Or is it figurative and you can't feel anything at all? or some arrogant person?

On the authority of Abu 'Abdullah al-Nu'man bin Bashir (ra) who said: I heard the Messenger of Allah(sas) say:

> "The halal is clear and the haram is clear, and between them are matters unclear that are unknown to most people. Whoever is wary of these unclear matters has absolved his religion and honor. And whoever indulges in them has indulged in the haram. It is like a shepherd who herds his sheep too close to preserved sanctuary, and they will eventually graze in it. Every king has a sanctuary, and the sanctuary of Allah is what He has made haram. There lies within the body a piece of flesh. If it is sound, the whole body is sound; and if it is corrupted, the whole body is corrupted. Verily this piece is the heart."
>   [Bukhari & Muslim]

Comment: Would you mind sharing some examples as else you leave us guessing what you refer to. The question might be about Tafseer, hadith-interpretation or fatwa-explanation or terminology.

Comment: alright fixed it

Answer (score 2):

"Hardened heart" is metaphorical.

> ثم قست قلوبكم من بعد ذلك فهي كالحجارة أو أشد قسوة وإن من الحجارة لما
>   يتفجر منه الأنهار وإن منها لما يشقق فيخرج منه الماء وإن منها لما يهبط
>   من خشية الله وما الله بغافل عما تعملون (Then your hearts became
>   hardened after that, being like stones or even harder. For indeed,
>   there are stones from which rivers burst forth, and there are some of
>   them that split open and water comes out, and there are some of them
>   that fall down for fear of Allah . And Allah is not unaware of what
>   you do). - [Qur'an 2:74](https://quran.com/2/74).

Above Allah (ﷻ) uses rocks as a simile, saying the hearts of the wrongdoers are *like stones or even harder*! He even points out that some rocks are softer than their hearts are! SubhanAllah. This is in a metaphorical sense, meaning arrogance, insincerity to truth, etc. It doesn't mean it's physically any harder within your chest.